# Type of object of unions is allowing all keys

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to define a type that is either `{ id: string}` or `{ firstName: string; lastName: string}`.

So I wrote this code:

```
type Ided = {
  id: string;
};

type User = { id: string } | {
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
};

const user: User = {
  id: '1',
  firstName: 'John',
  lastName: 'Doe',
  foo: true
}
```

However this code is allowing all three keys of `id` `firstName` and `lastName`. It is only throwing error for the key of `foo`. Is there a way to accomplish this union?

This is the typescript playground:

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgJhOUC8UDeAoKUCWcBcUAzsAE44B2A5gNwYC+dGokUAqkRKSurgcWUpUo9KAB90WKADMcpEgDkAhgFsIhEuWp1sAGyWLV6gVtoMmAYwD2FElACunUoQ5cembHkIByAIzeAGilZeWBlNR8AKSsACwpAqX1DCKhvABErCATsaSsrQjJ7CAYgA

Comment: Please see the answer to the linked question for information.

Comment: Oh whoops, thanks very much for that I missed it! @jcalz